# How to get product collections by set of ids in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, collection, orm

I want something like the "IN CLAUSE" in MYSQL via magento2 ORM, for example:

```
select * from product where id in (...)
```

but by using `getCollection` in magento 2 to get something like this:

```
$this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('id','in',[...]);
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10):

Try below code:

```
$this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array(
                                        'in' => array(3,8,9,207))
                                        );
```

Answer (score 7):

```
  <?php
  namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block;
 class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
       \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory 
        $productCollectionFactory,        
    array $data = []
)
{    
       $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

// getproductcollection

public function getProductCollection()
{
 Ids=array(1,2,3);
 $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
 $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');   //semicolon is missing                  
 $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $Ids]);
 return $collection;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')  semicolon is missing

Answer (score 6):

Yeah you can do the following:

```
$this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',['in' => [...]]);
```

Comment: what is the difference between using filter with 'entity_id' & 'id' ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want get the collection which **keep its ids order that is not ASC or DESC**, you could use codes like below:

```
$ids = '4,5,3,1,2';
$collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
        ->addFieldToFilter('id', ['in' => $ids])
$collection->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(entity_id,$ids)"));
```